# setInterval and React hooks produces unexpected results

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following component defined in my app scaffolded using create-react:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Play = props => {
  const [currentSecond, setCurrentSecond] = useState(1);
  let timer;
  const setTimer = () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (currentSecond < props.secondsPerRep) {
        setCurrentSecond(() => currentSecond + 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  setTimer();
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>{currentSecond}</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Play;
```

And `currentSecond` is updated every second until it hits the `props.secondsPerRep` however if I try to start the `setInterval` from a click handler:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Play = props => {
  const [currentSecond, setCurrentSecond] = useState(1);
  let timer;
  const setTimer = () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (currentSecond < props.secondsPerRep) {
        setCurrentSecond(() => currentSecond + 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={setTimer}>Start</button>
        <p>{currentSecond}</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Play;
```

Then `currentSecond` within the `setInterval` callback always returns to the initial value, i.e. 1.

Any help greeeeeeatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line `setCurrentSecond(() => currentSecond + 1);` because you are only calling `setTimer` once, your interval will always be closed over the initial state  where `currentSecond` is 1.

Luckily, you can easily remedy this by accessing the actual current state via the args in the function you pass to `setCurrentSecond` like `setCurrentSecond(actualCurrentSecond => actualCurrentSecond + 1)`

Also, you want to be very careful arbitrarily defining intervals in the body of functional components like that because they won't be cleared properly, like if you were to click the button again, it would start another interval and not clear up the previous one.

I'd recommend checking out this blog post because it would answer any questions you have about intervals + hooks: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 1):

https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ is a great post to look at and learn more about what's going on. The React useState hook doesn't play nice with setInterval because it only gets the value of the hook in the first render, then keeps reusing that value rather than the updated value from future renders.

In that post, Dan Abramov gives an example custom hook to make intervals work in React that you could use. That would make your code look more like this. Note that we have to change how we trigger the timer to start with another state variable.

```
const Play = props => {
  const [currentSecond, setCurrentSecond] = React.useState(1);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = React.useState(false);
  useInterval(() => {
    if (currentSecond < props.secondsPerRep) {
      setCurrentSecond(currentSecond + 1);
    }
  }, isRunning ? 1000 : null);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setIsRunning(true)}>Start</button>
        <p>{currentSecond}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I went ahead and put an example codepen together for your use case if you want to play around with it and see how it works.

https://codepen.io/BastionTheDev/pen/XWbvboX

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're code is closing over the `currentSecond` value from the render before you clicked on the button. That is javascript does not know about re-renders and hooks. You do want to set this up slightly differently.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const Play = ({ secondsPerRep }) => {
  const secondsPassed = useRef(1)
  const [currentSecond, setCurrentSecond] = useState(1);
  const [timerStarted, setTimerStarted] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;

    if(timerStarted) {
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (secondsPassed.current < secondsPerRep) {
          secondsPassed.current =+ 1

          setCurrentSecond(secondsPassed.current)
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    return () => void clearInterval(timer)
  }, [timerStarted])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setTimerStarted(!timerStarted)}>
          {timerStarted ? Stop : Start}
        </button>
        <p>{currentSecond}</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Play;
```

Why do you need a `ref` and the state? If you would only have the state the cleanup method of the effect would run every time you update your state. Therefore, you don't want your state to influence your effect. You can achieve this by using the `ref` to count the seconds. Changes to the ref won't run the effect or clean it up.

However, you also need the state because you want your component to re-render once your condition is met. But since the updater methods for the state (i.e. `setCurrentSecond`) are constant they also don't influence the effect.

Last but not least I've decoupled setting up the interval from your counting logic. I've done this with an extra state that switches between `true` and `false`. So when you click your button the state switches to `true`, the effect is run and everything is set up. If you're components unmounts, or you stop the timer, or the `secondsPerRep` prop changes the old interval is cleared and a new one is set up.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess that use ref to solve it is a little bit overkill

Answer (score 0):

Try that. The problem was that you're not using the state that is received by the `setCurrentSecond` function and the function `setInterval` don't see the state changing.

```
const Play = props => {
  const [currentSecond, setCurrentSecond] = useState(1);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState();
  const onClick = () => {
    setTimer(setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentSecond((state) => {
        if (state < props.secondsPerRep) {
          return state + 1;
        }
        return state;
      });
    }, 1000));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick} disabled={timer}>Start</button>
        <p>{currentSecond}</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```